# Bottom toolbar for all screens in iOS

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development and have a question about what component I should be using for a particular UI aspect.  The app I am working on has need for a toolbar to go across the bottom and at times to be visible across all screens.  This toolbar is going to be used to manage the playing/pausing of some audio files which will play as the user navigates between screens within the app.  My question is should I be using a Toolbar, a Navigation Bar or something else to achieve this?

Comment: You can use a UIToolbar but you can use a standard UIView with buttons as well. There is no preference for such a use case in iOS. The real deal here is how to embed this item in your view controllers hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for that feedback, can you elaborate a little more by what you mean around embedding the toolbar items in the view controllers hierarchy?  Would it be embedded in one view controller and displayed in multiple views?

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

To create such a toolbar you can use whichever component you want. There is no built-in solution on iOS for such a scenario and there is anything in the [human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/) that may help you to make this decision.

From my perspective, the problem here is how to make this toolbar visible on all your screens. This depends on your view controllers hierarchy which I know anything about.

#### Navigation controller

If you use `UInavigationController` to organize your screens you can use it's built-in toolbar to achieve your goal. The drawback is that the `UIToolbar` of `UINavigationController` is per item view controller so you will need to configure it each time a new `UIViewController` is pushed on the stack.

#### Containment

The general solution is using the [containment API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html). You can create let's say root view controller of your application which will contain your toolbar and will host other view controllers of your application. For the presentation purpose, I configured it on a storyboard using a container view. You can see it on the image below.

[image]

#### Modal presentations

Neither of above solutions will work when you decide to display a view controller modally. In this case, you will need to make additional effort to put the toolbar in such a view controller.

#### Other options

You probably won't be able to achieve that using `UITabBarController` unless you are very stubborn. But if you are new to iOS I don't recommend trying. The same is for `UIPageViewController`. I'm not sure about `UISplitViewController` because I have a very little experience with it.